# Why in this case the pid of the calling process and the new thread are the same?

Tags: c++, process

```
//compile and link with -pthread

#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <pthread.h>         

void *pthread_function( void *ptr ){

     printf("Hello from the new thread, my pid is %d\n", getpid());

}
    
int main() {

     printf("Hello from the calling process, my pid is %d\n", getpid());
     pthread_t thread;
     int ret;

     ret = pthread_create( &thread, NULL, pthread_function, NULL);

     if (ret){

         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", ret);

         exit(-1);    
      }

     /* Last thing that main() should do */

     pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

When I run this program, I got this result

> Hello from the calling process, my pid is 4445

> Hello from the new thread, my pid is 4445

Why in this case the pid of the calling process and the new thread are the same?

Comment: Why pid should be different no matter where do you get it in main thread or another?

Comment: pid is the **process** id. The thread is part of the process that created it.

Comment: `getpid()` returns a **process** ID, not a **thread** ID.  A process can have more than 1 thread.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`gettid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html).